# Write result for each pair of files in directory to file

Tags: bash, files

I would like to execute command on each pair of files in directory and write a result to a file, I would like to get matrix NxN of results.
I've started:

```
for file1 in some_directory/*.txt; 
do 
    filename1=$(basename "$file1")
    for file2 in some_directory/*.txt; 
    do 
        //here python script should be run 
        python script.py file1 file2
        //and result should be written to file, seperate by space
    done
    //here should be new line
done
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't know bash. Could anyone help me finish it? Thank you in advance

Comment: This subsite is about Ubuntu. Programming questions should be asked on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: you can print output with python and ">> file".
In your bash script: 
{my command to run the python script} >> output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/bash --
(cd some_directory ;\
 for file1 in *.txt ; do
   for file2 in *.txt ; do
#    here python script should be run
     printf "%s " "$(python /path/to/script.py "${file1}" "${file2}")"
   done
   printf "\n"
 done ) > result.file
```

*note*: `/path/to/script.py` must be replaced with the full pathname of `script.py` script.

The whole block is inclosed in `(...)`. All commands inside are executed into a subshell. This is used to group and capture their output and to make all commands execute in the `some_directory`, thanks to the first line with `cd` command.

`"${file1}"` and `"${file2}"` are used to reference the values of these variables safely.

`"$( ... )"` is executing the command inside, and group output into a single string thanks to the double-quotes.

`printf "%s " "$( ... )"` prints the result of the `python` script with an additional space.

`printf "\n"` prints a new line.

`> result.file` redirects all output generated with all commands inside the subshell into the file named `result.file` in the current directory.

It has been tested with weird filenames and it seems safe.